# Problem in textfield and prenventing enter key making new line

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

[image: the picture]

Like you see here the text is insered in the middle of the text area.

the CSS code :

```
.form-control {
    height: 300px;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #212529;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 1px solid #ced4da;
    appearance: none;
    border-radius: 0.375rem;
    transition: border-color .15s ease-in-out,box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
    }
```

the JSX code : `<input type="textfield" class="form-control" id="text" name="comment">`

that's my first problem the second one is that, i made a a function that prevent submitting when the user hit the enter button, but the problem is that he could not go to a new line :
the function is :

```
 const handleKeyPress = (event)=>{
    if (event.key === 'Enter') {
      event.preventDefault();
      
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

**First:** your problem is with the text vertical alignement in the textfield. I don't see any css property that make your text in the center that you show on the image. checkout the parent css selectors to see if there is anyone that conflict with it.

Also use `<textarea>` instead of `<input type="text">`.

```css
.form-control {
    height: 300px;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #212529;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 1px solid #ced4da;
    appearance: none;
    border-radius: 0.375rem;
    transition: border-color .15s ease-in-out,box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
    }
```

```html
<textarea class="form-control">TEXT AREA CONTENT</textarea>
```

**Second:** To stop submitting a form, it's not a good to prevent entering the ENTER key. You should prevent submitting the form.

Add this function to the `sumbit` event listener of the form `onSumbit` if your are using JSX.

```
const preventSubmitForm = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
}
```